# User defined template constraints to accept only a user-defined template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

Is there a way to create your own enable_if like condition?

I have a template class: `Foo<int, int, int>` and I have another template class which takes a type: `Template <T> class Bar`.

I'd like to constrain the `Bar` class such that the type it takes may only be any of the `Foo` class specialisations. Eg, can take `Foo<0, 0 ,1>` but can't take type int.

Is there a short and neat way of requiring this constraint through a user-defined enable_if? Is there a better method I haven't considered? Ideally the solution would be relatively compact and clear, possibly in the way std::is_arithmetic works.

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pull out any library types. The easiest way would be a good old specialization:

```
template <typename> class Bar;

template<int a, int b, int c>
class Bar<Foo<a, b, c>> {
  // Define `Bar`
};
```

Instantiating `Bar` with a type that is a `Foo<...>` would choose the specialization, while instantiating it with any other type will hit the dead end that is the incomplete class declaration of `Bar<T>`.

Comment: (Sorry switched devices and can’t find other account) Thanks for the suggestion, I had thought this would require calling the class via Bar<0,0, 1> rather than the preferred Bar<Foo<0, 0, 1>>

Comment: @user7119460 - No, that's not how specialization works. It still expects a `Foo`.